# how to isolate the style (css+html) from php

Tags: php, html, css, include, styles

how can i isolate the style ([css](/questions/tagged/css)+[html](/questions/tagged/html)) from  [php](/questions/tagged/php), like put in the php file just some lines including by it the whole  [style](/questions/tagged/style) or theme.

ex:

```
echo 
    eval_template("header") .
    eval_template("body") .
    eval_template("footer")
```

So in future i can change the whole style without touch the php files
**any idea ?**

Comment: Awesome question: as in, why don't *more* people think about this separation! .. anyway, search for "PHP template" or similar; then see if/how any of the *existing* solutions apply. This will allow constructing a better (and more directed question). In any case, HTML is relatively hard to separate *entirely* as it is structure-dependent (the range of separation varies with approaches/patterns: template with logic? bind-only? MVP? adapters?), but CSS is relative easy to separate with just normal external stylesheets.

Comment: I do with `ob_start` or `requires` ..

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways how you could do this...

Here's a tutorial on templating in plain PHP
http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-templating.html

You can also take a look at the many template engines out there.
twig is one of them: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I enjoy to do it manually.

PHP should not return both css and html code, or even better, it shoukd not return client-side code at all but rather dependencies to specific parts. You never want to modify a file that contains a lot of different things.

To separate css+html from the php code, what I usually do is a hierarchy done with include("..."); and include_once("..."). For example : include_once("header.php") > include("menu.php") > html semantic with css classes correctly initialized according to current context.

Then you import your css / js external scripts in header.php so that you never have to modify the whole thing unless everything changes or if you have a complete feature to add to the website. Same is possible for every sections of the website.

Hope this helps, for me it is incredibly reducing debug-time since everything important has to be done only once, then at the top of it, you can seperate as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of template engines you can use to do that, i prefer use twig, that is integrated with symfony2 framework.

Twig is wonderful because is very easy to use and very flexible, you can use inheritance to create a common layout which can be extended and overwriten in some some part using special tags. This is a guide i've find on Symfony website but is very usefull to understand the logic behind twig: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html