# A Little Advice On PHP

Tags: php

I have been taught about embedding PHP inside HTML OR HTML inside PHP. I would like to start writing some apps in PHP and would like to know from you guys which one of the options to use.

At the moment i don't know which option to use so i decided to ask for some advice. It may be that one is better than the other in general.

I am about to develop real-world applications so i want to know which one to use. May be it may affect my future colleagues etc...

It may also be that the open source community and PHP programmers in general have a tradition of using one option.

Which one is mostly used in real-world applications?

Just need some advice.

Thank you.

Comment: I like to use something like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) to include HTML with. Templating makes life easier. This keeps PHP and HTML relatively separate.

Comment: @noko What about performance? Does smarty affect performance of the application?

Comment: Personally, I think you should avoid situations where you might be thinking of doing either explicitly. PHP can be used as a direct (and fast) templating agent itself (as WordPress does, for instance), but embedding either "by design" within or around your *actual application code* is a limiting and self-defeating approach. You should be templating (in most cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to stick a bit with vanilla PHP [vars, operators, loops, conditions, core functions], then pick a framework [Symfony, Zend Framework, YII, Codeigniter]and follow its conventions and principles.

About PHP vs HTML, the idea is to keep business and presentational logic separated, i.e. you should gather all the stuff you need to display in a piece of your code, *then* in another section you write the HTML using as little PHP as you can [just for echoing values or performing loops for table population, etc.].

Then you'll get into topic such as templates, Model-View-Controller architecture...but don't go further now.

Comment: @moonwave99 - Good answer: I agree completely :)

Answer (score 4):

1) As you're implicitly asking, "separation of HTML and PHP" is a Good Thing.

2) The basic answer is "templating".

3) Here are some good links:

- [how to isolate the style (css+html) from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478290/how-to-isolate-the-style-csshtml-from-php)
- http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-templating.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29

I should emphasize that "HTML in PHP" vs "PHP in HTML" is *not* an either/or situtation.  Some pages will be mostly PHP (which might emit a little HTML); other pages might be mostly HTML (which might contain a bit of PHP).  This is normal and Good - it is *not* necessarily a problem.  IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

It'l be much easier to read the HTML code if you write it as HTML code and embed PHP in it. Ideally seperate it as much as possible.

[See this question.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6359/16125)

Answer (score -1):

You will need a template engine, there are a lot
of templating engines but the cleanest one is [Jade](https://github.com/everzet/jade.php),
not only jade is clean, but it also compiles to plain php.

hope that helps :)

Comment: Smarty, Flexy and other templating systems often cache a PHP'd version of the template text for reuse (until recompilation), depending on configuration. Not sure what the definition of "clean" is, but usually a templating agent does something specific (Smarty is more or less PHP in a can, Flexy is a limited "designer's foot-saving approach", etc.

Comment: @JaredFarrish When i say clean i mean [readable](http://jade-lang.com/)

Comment: So it's like CoffeeScript for PHP? (Note as well there's a Mustache port for PHP.)